# C# Coding Style in asp.net mvc app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I and my team starting new project with asp.net mvc (before write in c++) and i want to use best code style practice for asp.net mvc because its very important thing for long project. You guys who have good experience in asp.net mvc can recommend me good code styling rules?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is too broad to be answered here. I would recommend you start with [some tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and also there's the excellent [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210079) book from Steven Sanderson you might take a look at.

Also here's an [excellent guide](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/06/29/how-we-do-mvc-view-models.aspx) you should definitely checkout. It is based on a couple of golden rules that should be respected if you want to follow good practices.

Comment: Thanks i read this book but i want to know professional opinion who write big project in this technology. Thanks

Comment: @Sanja, you want an opinion on what? Your question is too broad. You ask for *best coding style in ASP.NET MVC*. Do you really expect to get an answer for such a question? If there was a straightforward answer people wouldn't bother writing entire books on the subject. Or maybe you have some more specific question?

Comment: Maybe you are right Darin this question is too broad, but thank you for response )

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links describing good practices for coding ASP.NET MVC:

[ASP.NET MVC Best Practices (Part 1)](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx)

[ASP.NET MVC Best Practices (Part 2)](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/03/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-2.aspx)

http://www.slideshare.net/simonech/aspnet-mvc-best-practices

But the best option is to read some ASP.NET MVC book like "PRO ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework" or "ASP.NET MVC in Action"

Answer (score 1):

If its real coding style that you are looking for, I really recommend [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), that tool gives you tons of good advice while your are typing. It helps you respect the naming convention standard set by Microsoft which you can consult [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx).

---

Answer (score 0):

There's just too much to say about ASP.NET MVC..

I'd suggest you to buy and read a book if t is a very important long project, Wrox and Manning books are 2 good choices